# Gradle experimental JNI OpenCv arm 64-v8a linker error

Tags: android, opencv, linker, java-native-interface

I have a project which uses opencv android sdk and in order to speed thing up decided to implement some functions in C++.

Anyway I am using gradle experimental plugin 0.4.0 and when to build for arm64-v8a, linker tells me it could not find the libraries in the jniLibs folder.. tries many different variations and I believe that the path is correct (checked on the terminal by using cd)

this is my app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application' model{



android {

    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
   /* sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs' //set libs as .so's location instead of jni
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call with auto-generated Android.mk file
    }*/
    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = "com.sketchcamera.camera"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        versionCode = 105
        versionName = "1.05"
    }


}


android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
        //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        //jniDebuggable = true
        //  signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        //jniDebuggable = true
    }
}
android.productFlavors {
    create("AArch-64") {
        ndk.with{
            abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")

            File curDir = file('./')
            curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
            String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/"

            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")

        }
    }
    create("arm") {
        ndk.with{
            abiFilters.add("armeabi")

            File curDir = file('./')
            curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
            String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/"

            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")

        }
    }
    create("armv7") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")

            File curDir = file('./')
            curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
            String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/"
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_core.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_highgui.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_imgproc.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_java3.so")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ml.a")
            ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libopencv_ts.a")

        }
    }
}

android.ndk {
    moduleName = "opencv_fast_processing"
    cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
    cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
    cppFlags.add("-I${file("/home/onur/Masaüstü/Home/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include")}".toString())
    ldLibs.addAll(["android", "EGL", "GLESv2", "dl", "log", "z"])
    stl = "gnustl_shared"
}
// android.useLibrary = 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

}

Everything is fine if I use arm7 or arm but if compile with arm64-v8a it linker gives this error:

```
/home/onur/Android/android-ndk-r11c/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/onur/AndroidStudioProjects/SketchCamera/app/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.a
```

and the same error for the other files..
As I said berfore, I am sure that the path is correct but do not know what is -l in front of the /home (Don't have much experience with C and gnu)

I am new to this JNI things and most probably doing something stupid. Thanks for any help

Comment: OpenCV for Android from official sources comes without arm64-v8a libraries

Comment: I believe it is much easier to work with OpenCV through ndkBuild or CMake configurations, both fully supply by the official Gradle client in Android Studio 2.2

Answer (score 3):

I was faced to the same problem here but with `libcrypto` (OpenSSL).
I managed to solve it by changing my `build.gradle` file. Instead using `productFlavors` I changed to `repositores` section as the following example:

Remove this piece of code:

```
abis {
        create("x86") {
            ldLibs.add("${file("src/main/jniLibs/x86/libcrypto.so")}".toString())
        }
        create("x86_64") {
            ldLibs.add("${file("src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/libcrypto.so")}".toString())
        }
        create("armeabi-v7a") {
            ldLibs.add("${file("src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.so")}".toString())
        }
        create("arm64-v8a") {
            ldLibs.add("${file("src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.so")}".toString())
        }
    }
```

And add this one:

```
repositories {
    prebuilt(PrebuiltLibraries) {
        prebuiltSharedlib {
            binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/jniLibs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libcrypto.so")
            }
        }
    }
}
android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            dependencies {
                library "prebuiltSharedlib"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally set up the ABI filters inside the `ndk` section:

```
abiFilters.addAll(["armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"])
```

Hope it helps.